# Is it possible to control xterm (or specifically a process that xterm has started) from another process?

Tags: terminal, scripting, process, xterm, stdin

If I start a process with xterm like this (where omxplayer is the process xterm is starting):

```
xterm -fullscreen -fg black -bg black -e omxplayer -o hdmi -r %f
```

Is it possible for me to write to xterm's standard input via a different process to control the omxplayer? If so, how?

(I'm pretty unfamiliar with linux terminology so please excuse if I'm stating this incorrectly.)

**Update**

As per @strugee's comment, I'm not aiming to write to xterm's standard input, but rather I'm aiming to write to omxplayer's standard input.

Comment: note: you wouldn't be writing to your `xterm`'s stdin. you'd either be writing to the stdin of the shell running inside the xterm, or you'd be writing to `omxplayer`'s stdin.

Comment: thanks strugee, I've updated my question to reflect your point. I have to have a bit of a think about all this to get my head around what I'm actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: absolutely! I don't want to explain it all in a comment, but you might want to ask a new question about the difference between xterm's stdin and the shell inside the xterm's stdin, if it doesn't make sense already.

Comment: **`omxplayer` isn't controlled from stdin.**  It has a threaded, event based interface, meaning it takes control of keyboard input as the foreground process.  That's why you don't need to hit return, etc, you just hit a key.  Controlling stuff like that remotely is complicated (in fact, controlling it remotely may not be possible at all).

Comment: Okay, in fact I may be wrong about that -- you can do this by putting the terminal into "raw" mode and polling stdin.  So that could be how it happens, in which case writing to stdin should work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Way of running `screen` pseudo tty

There you need to run your command in an *intermediary tty manager*.

```
screen -d -m omxplayer -o hdmi -r %f
```

than

```
xterm -fullscreen -fg grey -bg black -e screen -R
```

This let you detach and reconnect your *screen* anytime you want: hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, than <kbd>d</kbd> for detach from screen session and `screen -R` in any terminal console to reconnect.

Have a look at `man screen` for more infos.

Answer (score -1):

In order write to omxplayer's standard input you can do this:

> echo 'hello'> /proc/$(pidof omxplayer)/fd/1

**Update**

My previous advice was poorly documented and wrong, I apologize for it.

[This link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=7987&p=122561) contains pointers to some [projects](https://github.com/jbaiter/pyomxplayer) that attempt to control omxplayer by other means, but they often need to run it directly, without xterm.

Comment: Actually you can't do this. Firstly `fd/1` is STDOUT, not STDIN. But even if you use `fd/0` (which is STDIN), it's a symlink to the TTY, and anything written to the TTY simply gets displayed as output on that terminal.

Comment: Also found a DBus-based controller for omxplayer https://code.google.com/p/rocksources/wiki/OMXPlayerDbus